# How to group variables then subtract by rows in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, row, lag

I am trying to group the variables group, type, and year. Each group, type, and year have a particular code that changes from year to year. I want to create a column called "difference" where, if the group and type has a code of 200 in one year and 210 the next year, the "difference" column will register it as an increase in 10.

```
group <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
type <- c("small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large")
year <- c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995,
          1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996,
          1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997)
code <- c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300,
          150, 150, 100, 200, 200, 200, 350, 320, 300,
          130, 170, 90, 210, 90, 80, 310, 300, 320)

df <- data.frame(group, type, year, code)
```

This is how the df looks like:

```
 group   type year code
1      A  small 1995  100
2      A medium 1995  100
3      A  large 1995  100
4      B  small 1995  200
5      B medium 1995  200
6      B  large 1995  200
7      C  small 1995  300
8      C medium 1995  300
9      C  large 1995  300
10     A  small 1996  150
11     A medium 1996  150
12     A  large 1996  100
13     B  small 1996  200
14     B medium 1996  200
15     B  large 1996  200
16     C  small 1996  350
17     C medium 1996  320
18     C  large 1996  300
19     A  small 1997  130
20     A medium 1997  170
21     A  large 1997   90
22     B  small 1997  210
23     B medium 1997   90
24     B  large 1997   80
25     C  small 1997  310
26     C medium 1997  300
27     C  large 1997  320
```

I want the following output:

```
group <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
type <- c("small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large")
year <- c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995,
          1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996,
          1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997)
code <- c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300,
          150, 150, 100, 200, 200, 200, 350, 320, 300,
          130, 170, 90, 210, 90, 80, 310, 300, 320)
difference <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
               50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 20, 0,
               -20, 20, -10, 10, 110, 120, -40, -20, 0)

df2 <- data.frame(group, type, year, code, difference)

   group   type year code difference
1      A  small 1995  100         NA
2      A medium 1995  100         NA
3      A  large 1995  100         NA
4      B  small 1995  200         NA
5      B medium 1995  200         NA
6      B  large 1995  200         NA
7      C  small 1995  300         NA
8      C medium 1995  300         NA
9      C  large 1995  300         NA
10     A  small 1996  150         50
11     A medium 1996  150         50
12     A  large 1996  100          0
13     B  small 1996  200          0
14     B medium 1996  200          0
15     B  large 1996  200          0
16     C  small 1996  350         50
17     C medium 1996  320         20
18     C  large 1996  300          0
19     A  small 1997  130        -20
20     A medium 1997  170         20
21     A  large 1997   90        -10
22     B  small 1997  210         10
23     B medium 1997   90        110
24     B  large 1997   80        120
25     C  small 1997  310        -40
26     C medium 1997  300        -20
27     C  large 1997  320          0
```

This is what I tried:

```
df3 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(group, type, year) %>%
  mutate(difference = code - lag(code))
```

The problem is that the lag seems to not take the grouping into consideration and is instead just subtracting from the row right before it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want the difference between year values of code then don’t group by year. The way you are doing it now you only have one row per grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update on OP request:
To get `0` we could use an `ifelse` statement:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group, type) %>% 
  mutate(difference= ifelse(is.na(lag(code)), 0, code - lag(code))) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

```
 group   type year code difference
1      A  small 1995  100          0
2      A medium 1995  100          0
3      A  large 1995  100          0
4      B  small 1995  200          0
5      B medium 1995  200          0
6      B  large 1995  200          0
7      C  small 1995  300          0
8      C medium 1995  300          0
9      C  large 1995  300          0
10     A  small 1996  150         50
11     A medium 1996  150         50
12     A  large 1996  100          0
13     B  small 1996  200          0
14     B medium 1996  200          0
15     B  large 1996  200          0
16     C  small 1996  350         50
17     C medium 1996  320         20
18     C  large 1996  300          0
19     A  small 1997  130        -20
20     A medium 1997  170         20
21     A  large 1997   90        -10
22     B  small 1997  210         10
23     B medium 1997   90       -110
24     B  large 1997   80       -120
25     C  small 1997  310        -40
26     C medium 1997  300        -20
27     C  large 1997  320         20
```

First(answer):
As @IRTFM already points out. group only by `group` and `type`.
It gives almost the same output. Note the last row is different.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group, type) %>% 
  mutate(difference= code - lag(code)) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

```
 group   type year code difference
1      A  small 1995  100         NA
2      A medium 1995  100         NA
3      A  large 1995  100         NA
4      B  small 1995  200         NA
5      B medium 1995  200         NA
6      B  large 1995  200         NA
7      C  small 1995  300         NA
8      C medium 1995  300         NA
9      C  large 1995  300         NA
10     A  small 1996  150         50
11     A medium 1996  150         50
12     A  large 1996  100          0
13     B  small 1996  200          0
14     B medium 1996  200          0
15     B  large 1996  200          0
16     C  small 1996  350         50
17     C medium 1996  320         20
18     C  large 1996  300          0
19     A  small 1997  130        -20
20     A medium 1997  170         20
21     A  large 1997   90        -10
22     B  small 1997  210         10
23     B medium 1997   90       -110
24     B  large 1997   80       -120
25     C  small 1997  310        -40
26     C medium 1997  300        -20
27     C  large 1997  320         20
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Is it possible for, when code goes from Inf in 1995 to Inf in 1996, the difference comes out as 0?

Comment: Please see my update!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff` in `ave`.

```
dat[order(dat$group, dat$type), ] |>
  transform(diff=ave(code, group, type, FUN=\(x) c(NA, diff(x)))) |>
  (\(x) x[order(as.numeric(rownames(x))), ])()  ## optional, to reorder rows
#    group   type year code diff
# 1      A  small 1995  100   NA
# 2      A medium 1995  100   NA
# 3      A  large 1995  100   NA
# 4      B  small 1995  200   NA
# 5      B medium 1995  200   NA
# 6      B  large 1995  200   NA
# 7      C  small 1995  300   NA
# 8      C medium 1995  300   NA
# 9      C  large 1995  300   NA
# 10     A  small 1996  150   50
# 11     A medium 1996  150   50
# 12     A  large 1996  100    0
# 13     B  small 1996  200    0
# 14     B medium 1996  200    0
# 15     B  large 1996  200    0
# 16     C  small 1996  350   50
# 17     C medium 1996  320   20
# 18     C  large 1996  300    0
# 19     A  small 1997  130  -20
# 20     A medium 1997  170   20
# 21     A  large 1997   90  -10
# 22     B  small 1997  210   10
# 23     B medium 1997   90 -110
# 24     B  large 1997   80 -120
# 25     C  small 1997  310  -40
# 26     C medium 1997  300  -20
# 27     C  large 1997  320   20
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used